# How to put MySql Data from PHP to Cocoa Application Table View

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, macos, uitableview

I would like to know how to populate a Cocoa Table View (in objective-c) for Mac Os with MySql Data relayed with php.
For instance,
I would output all the values from the database to a php file called outMac.php
I would then like the Cocoa application to harvest the data and put it in the table...
Does anyone know how to do this. 
I can't seem to find this anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I could see 2 options :
1) you can call an php url that generates an xml or json output that you interpret in your objective-C code, this would then just men you're calling a url and read the php's echos
2) you can go for the full scale web service as in soap (check http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/0/page/1), this is much more secure on the server side but requires probably a bit more work

Once you've got the data in an array it is pretty straightforward to output on a table view.
I'm not sure which level of information you're looking for but this would be the outline.